# How to replace a string in an existing file in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to replace the word "blue" with "red" in all text files named as 1_classification.dat, 2_classification.dat and so on. I want to edit the same file so I tried the following code, but it does not work. Where am I going wrong?

```
@files = glob("*_classification.dat");
foreach my $file (@files)
{
    open(IN,$file) or die $!;
    <IN>;
    while(<IN>)
    {
        $_ = '~s/blue/red/g';
        print IN $file;
    }
    close(IN)
}
```

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Use a one-liner:

```
$ perl -pi.bak -e 's/blue/red/g' *_classification.dat
```

---

**Explanation**

- `-p` processes, then prints `<>` line by line
- `-i` activates in-place editing. Files are backed up using the `.bak` extension
- The regex substitution acts on the implicit variable, which are the contents of the file, line-by-line

Comment: Yeah, or no quotes at all, if the code doesn't contain spaces.

Comment: Using the `*` globbing in arguments does not seem to work in windows.

Comment: I notied that on windows I had to used double quotes around the regex

Comment: `glob` hack to support wildcard command line arguments (`*.dat`) for Windows users: `BEGIN { @ARGV = map +glob, @ARGV }`

Comment: What if search and replacement strings are in variables? `perl -pi -e 's/$oldKey/$trimmedNewKey/g' AppConstants.txt`, did not work for me

Comment: @nr5, Look at my answer below. I had a case it didn't work for me either and the issue was the Regular Expression processing,

Comment: How do I do substitution atomically (per-file, not per-line) without any backup files? Should i use -i or not? I don't understand what "in-place editing" means. I want to do substitution in files that I'm watching for changes, so it needs to be atomic.

Comment: @nr5 The problem is that bash variables don't expand within single quoted strings. Use double quotes.

Answer (score 22):

None of the existing answers here have provided a complete example of how to do this from within a script (not a one-liner). Here is what I did:

```
rename($file, $file . '.bak');
open(IN, '<' . $file . '.bak') or die $!;
open(OUT, '>' . $file) or die $!;
while(<IN>)
{
    $_ =~ s/blue/red/g;
    print OUT $_;
}
close(IN);
close(OUT);
```

Comment: ugly misuse of $_

Answer (score 14):

> `$_='~s/blue/red/g';`

Uh, what??

Just

```
s/blue/red/g;
```

or, if you insist on using a variable (which is not necessary when using $_, but I just want to show the right syntax):

```
$_ =~ s/blue/red/g;
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be done using a single line:

```perl
perl -pi.back -e 's/oldString/newString/g;' inputFileName
```

Pay attention that `oldString` is processed as a [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).
In case the string contains any of `{}[]()^$.|*+?` ([The special characters for Regular Expression syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Syntax)) make sure to escape them unless you want it to be processed as a regular expression.
Escaping it is done by `\`, so `\[`.