# Search and replace a particular string in a file using Perl

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace a string in an existing file in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994947/how-to-replace-a-string-in-an-existing-file-in-perl)

I need to create a subroutine that does a search and replace in file.

Here's the contents of myfiletemplate.txt:

```
CATEGORY1=youknow_<PREF>  
CATEGORY2=your/<PREF>/goes/here/
```

Here's my replacement string: `ABCD`

I need to replace all instances of `<PREF>` to `ABCD`

Comment: The right column [is your friend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994947/how-to-replace-a-string-in-an-existing-file-in-perl).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

open(FILE, "</tmp/yourfile.txt") || die "File not found";
my @lines = <FILE>;
close(FILE);

foreach(@lines) {
   $_ =~ s/<PREF>/ABCD/g;
}

open(FILE, ">/tmp/yourfile.txt") || die "File not found";
print FILE @lines;
close(FILE);
```

Perhaps it i a good idea not to write the result back to your original file; instead write it to a copy and check the result first.

Comment: There is no need of pushing data into another array. You may modify `@lines` in-place.

Comment: including $! in the die message, `die "File not found $!";` has helped me find what is wrong before.

Answer (score 44):

A one liner:

```
perl -pi.back -e 's/<PREF>/ABCD/g;' inputfile
```

Comment: This saved my day, thank you!

Comment: @sasi_personal: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Comment: Anyone else wondering, the `.back` creates backup files. You can remove it.

Comment: I have been trying to replace the first occurrence of a string via variables like: `perl -pi -e 's/$oldKey/$trimmedNewKey/g' AppConstants.txt`, but nothing happens. oldKey does exists in the txt file and trimmedNewKey also has value in it.

Comment: @nr5: Probably because you haven't defined `$oldKey`.

Comment: I tried this with strings with `=` and it fails. Any idea why?

Comment: @Royi: I can't answer without more details. I think you should ask a new question with sample text and expected result.

Comment: I write `perl -pi.back -e 's/a = b;/a += b;/g;' MyCFile.c`. Yet `a = b` are not replaced.

Comment: @Royi: It should, may be you have more than 1 space around equal sign or tabulation instead of space. What is `a`? And `b`? Only single letter or expression? But, again, it is not te place to ask a question, ask your own separatly.

Comment: Think of `C` file I want to replace `a = b` by adding `b` to `a`. So replace `a = b;` by `a += b;`. Nothing but that. There is nothing special in the expression as doing it with PowerShell works (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir#comment102551724_20999154).

Comment: @Royi: Sorry, I don't get you. The regex is working fine for me. But, again, it is not te place to ask a question, ask your own separatly.

Comment: When I Googled I got this result. I think better policy is having all information here. I think `perl` process the strings as regex and hence the added information should be how to escape this mode and use "pure strings".

Comment: @Toto, Now I added the missing information to the answer to be complete for those who only want to replace strings and not utilize regular expressions syntax.

Comment: @Royi: I disagree with your edit. The question is how to replace literally `<PREF>` with `ABCD`. It's not about replacing any kind of string, there're other Q/As that solve this.

Comment: Since it was marked as duplicate of the more general case, I think it is viable. You can my comments and @nr5 are about general uses.

Answer (score 16):

You could also do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$^I = '.bak'; # create a backup copy 

while (<>) {
   s/<PREF>/ABCD/g; # do the replacement
   print; # print to the modified file
}
```

Invoke the script with by

```
./script.pl input_file
```

You will get a file named `input_file`, containing your changes, and a file named `input_file.bak`, which is simply a copy of the original file.