# Unexpected behavior with grep for replacing substrings

Tags: regex, replace, grep, substring, oh-my-zsh

I'm having some troubles understanding how to use grep to achieve an apparently simple task. I wanna match a substring that appears in a lot of files that I have but I wanna ignore the cases when this substring is preceded by a letter or a number

For example I have a bunch of files with lines like:

```
{ some word: ['bar-something', 'bar-somthing-else'] },
{ some text: ['bar-fab', 'bar-fab-foo', 'bar-eggs'] },
<bar-sometext>Hello World!</bar-sometext>
'bar-foobar-foo'
'bar-foo'
```

and I wanna replace all the bar- appearances for ket- but only if bar isn't preceded by a letter or number, for example

```
'bar-foobar-foo'
```

should be changed to

```
'ket-foobar-foo'
```

but I'm having some troubles because the grep command is not being consistent with their own rules

let me explain:

The command:

```
git grep -l 'bar-' | xargs sed -i '' -e 's/bar-/ket-/g'
```

almost work, the only problem is that it's also changing the bar that is preceded by letters or numbers:

`'bar-foobar-foo'` to `'ket-fooket-foo'`

To do some tests, before make the replacements I'm only matching with grep. I was expecting that the command

```
grep -E '[^a-zA-Z0-9]ket-' a.file
```

did the trick, but it's also matching any special character preceding the word ket-. For example, is matching

```
<bar-

'bar-

\bar-
```

(I remove the rest of the text for simplicity, the above is highlighted as the matched text) instead of only matching bar-. Why is doing that?, when I wasn't excluding letters or numbers, grep wasn't matching these preceding special characters.

How can I replace only bar- without matching anything else, but at the same time ignoring any case where this substring is preceded by any letter or number. My expected output for the example that I gave is:

```
{ some word: ['ket-something', 'ket-somthing-else'] },
{ some text: ['ket-fab', 'ket-fab-foo', 'ket-eggs'] },
<ket-sometext>Hello World!</ket-sometext>
'ket-foobar-foo'
'ket-foo'
```

BTW I'm using a mac and I having troubles to do the replacements, the command

```
git grep -l 'bar-' | xargs sed -i '' -e 's/bar-/ket-/g'
```

works pretty well in my Mac with oh-my-zsh terminal, I will appreciate any answer that closely look like the above command

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can do "sed" command two times to fix this and you don't need grep

`sed -i -e "s/'bar-/'ket-/g" <filename>`
`sed -i -e "s/<bar-/<ket-/g" <filename>`

Comment: Hi @Karthikeyan, that almost works (for this short example it only requires manage the case for the backslash), but I assume that I need to add a new line to treat each special case, for example a command like `sed -i -e "s/\bar-/\ket-/g" <filename>`. Now I need to figure out how to to apply it to all my files because they are thousands. The wildcard * is outputting this error message:  `sed: in-place editing only works for regular files`. But thanks, your answer surely is an excellent  starting point to build one answer that works for my intended case

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, you should use another instrument, that supports lookbehind assertions.

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/(?<![\p{L}\d])bar/test/g' file.txt
```

- `-p` processes, then prints `<>` line by line,
- `-i` activates in-place editing. `file.txt` will be backed up with the `.bak` extension,
- `-e` means that the first argument is Perl one-liner, not a Perl executable file,
- `(?<!` is a negative lookbehind assertion,
- `\p{L}` is any letter.

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/6995010/6632736.

Comment: Note it is more efficient to join two single-char matching patterns into a character class, `(?<!\p{L}|\d)` => `(?<![\p{L}\d])`, to avoid extra backtracking at the start.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's/\([^[:alnum:]]\)bar/\1ket/g' file
```

This is a sed substitution in the form of `'s/pattern/replace/g'` where `g` means globally.

The matching pattern means: one non-alphanumeric character followed by "bar". The replacement is the character matched (`\1`) followed by `ket`. Whatever is nested between parentheses in the matching pattern, can be re-used into the replacement like `\1` `\2` and so on, until `\9`.

You can do it inplace, like in your example command (and with any macOS    specific adjustments). Also, `grep` is not being used for replacements, it only extracts text, and there is usually no reason to use it along with awk or sed.

Comment: Hi @thanasisp I used grep to make the replacements in all my files inside directories and subdirectories recursively. Because I have thousands of files I need a way to apply the changes to all my files. Your solution for some reason is not matching the case where a line starts with

Comment: You can do this recursively for all the files you want. `find` would do it, or a glob file argument. For example: `find ... | xargs sed -i ...`

Comment: Also I see it matches lines starting with `-`, if you have an example line that didn't match correctly, please update with this example.

Comment: Sorry, yesterday I edited my comment with the right example but apparently it wasn't updated. The cases that are not being matched are:
`bar-somthing`
`bar-another-thing`
that is, if 'bar' is starting the word, the above solution is skipping those cases. Also I would like to match the cases where the the substring `bar` is preceded by a blank space for example, I would like to replace:
`someTex moretext barSomeWord` with
`someTex moretext ketSomeWord`

Comment: Sorry I have no time now to follow any changes in this question, good luck and have a nice day!